# KitKat uninstalling app from device

Tags: applications, 4.4-kitkat, uninstallation

I ran into a weird issue on my Nexus 7 running 4.4.2. If I uninstall an app from the device, it still shows up in Settings -> Apps -> Downloaded at the bottom, and it says not installed. However, it prevents me from installing an apk via adb, reporting the app was still installed.

I had to do an adb uninstall and that completely removed the app.

What changed? What's the proper procedure to remove an app? The only thing that changed that I'm aware of is that now I'm using user profiles, but the app in question is not used in any other profiles.

Thoughts?

Comment: What steps did you take to uninstall the app from the device?

Comment: I've seen something similar when an app is installed in someone else's profile but not my own, so make *really* sure you don't still have it installed in any other profiles.

Comment: @DanHulme to uninstall, went to apps, tapped on app then Uninstall. The only way it goes away completely is if I do adb uninstall.

Comment: @Wyzard you are right...for some reason apps installed via adb install seem to go into all profiles, then removing it via Settings->Apps would remove it only from my current profile. Good catch! If you make your comment an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen something similar when an app is installed in someone else's profile but not my own, so make *really* sure you don't still have it installed in any other profiles.